# Ajax returns success but undefined array key error in browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm creating a plugin where if you click on a particular block, it sends an ajax request to update the number of clicks on that button to the database. This is the function that runs when that block is clicked:

```
clickHandler() {
    var myKeyVals = { question_id: 1, answer1click: true, answer2click: false }
    var saveData = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../wp-content/plugins/picker-plugin/inc/receiver.php",
        data: myKeyVals,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (resultData) { console.log(myKeyVals) }
    });
    saveData.error(function () { alert("Something went wrong"); });
}
```

I get the object in my console. But, I get an error that says undefined array key. This is my receiver php file:

```
<?php 

echo $_POST['question_id'];
```

I've included it in the index.php file so actually renders in the frontend if I write(say) echo "hello world". This is the full error it is throwing :

:  Undefined array key "question_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\plugdev\wp-content\plugins\picker-plugin\inc\receiver.php on line 3.

Comment: If I copy and paste that code into a couple of local files (and comment out the call to`saveData.error` -- I don't think that was ever a method on [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), but it certainly isn't in the latest jQuery), that works -- I don't get teh error you describe from the PHP. If I change the `success` function to log `resultData` (instead of `myKeyVals`), I get `"1"` in the console. So wherever the problem is, it's not in *that* code.

Comment: What’s the actual raw data that’s being sent? Check the developer tools’ network inspector. Is it sending the data as URL-encoded format or JSON or something else?

Comment: Could the error be because I'm executing it onClick of a button? It makes sense for it to say undefined in the beginning because it's not actually defined yet but, after clicking it doesn't update? Is that because it's php?

Comment: It’s because you’re somehow not sending a *form-encoded* POST request with the specific key. So the first thing to find out is: what exactly *are* you sending. Again refer back to my developer tool comment above.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - `dataType` is the type of data you expect **back**, not what you're sending (that's `contentType`). And the OP isn't sending JSON, they're sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (roughly, URI-encoded data), as that's the default for `jQuery.ajax`. It takes the JavaScript (not JSON) object you pass it and sends the properties as form fields.

Comment: @deceze, it sends an object . I've changed the code a little bit using the wordpress availabe functions. But, the issue is the same, 200 status code but nothing is being echoed when i do echo $_POST['question_id']

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73349650/problem-when-sending-an-ajax-post-request-in-wordpress

Here is the new code if you guys are familiar with setting it up with wordpress environment. The action function is supposed to echo the post request but it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

This works well !!

```
 var myKeyVals = { question_id: 1, answer1click: true, answer2click: false };
            var saveData = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "../wp-content/plugins/picker-plugin/inc/receiver.php",
                data: myKeyVals,
                success: function (resultData) {
                     console.log(resultData) 
                    },
                error : function () {
                     alert("Something went wrong"); 
                    }
            });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).