# Problem when sending an ajax post request in WordPress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I've read several articles on how to do this and all of them mention the same thing that I am using. I have two files for this:

In the receiver.php file:

```
<?php 
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'theActionFunction' );

function my_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/src/WyrRoute.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script');
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
function theActionFunction(){
   $theQuestion = $_POST['question_id'];
   echo $theQuestion; //doesn't show anything in the frontend
   wp_die();
}
echo "hello" //works if outside the function
```

The issue is that nothing inside this theActionFunction prints in the frontend. Anything I type outside shows in the frontend, there must be something basic that I'm missing here.

WyrRoute.js

```
clickHandler(e) {
    var ajax_url = my_ajax_object.ajax_url
    var data ={
        'action': 'my_action',
        'question_id': '10183'
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (xhr, x, checkStatus) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(checkStatus.status)
            console.log("success")
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.statusText);
            console.log("failure")
        }
    });
}
```

Ajax returns with 200 success, so no issue there, but for some reason, I can't get the $_POST['value'] to print in the frontend using php.

Comment: admin-ajax.php retuns 0

Comment: If your data type is JSON you can't echo your output. You must return JSON

Comment: @HowardE, how can I echo it to the frontend.  I have spent almost a day trying to get something/anything from ajax to the frontend using php.

Comment: Try using data type : 'HTML' and use exit() or die() instead of wp_die()

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.
Well, from what I'm seeing in the code, it looks ok. At first glance, the thing I noticed is that you are declaring the function called "theActionFunction", but you arent calling it anywhere. Again it may just be me, but, if the method isn't printing anything, right underneath it, put this:

```
theActionFunction();
```

And you should be good to go. In total, it should look like this:

```
function theActionFunction(){
   $theQuestion = $_POST['question_id'];
   echo $theQuestion; //This should now work
   wp_die();
}

theActionFunction();
```

Happy coding.